# How to add data-role="collapsible" in a div container

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

How can I add data-role="collapsible" in every div container with class "make_me_collapsible"?

```
<div class="make_me_collapsible"><h2>Header</h2><p>Content....</p></div>
```

Comment: `$(".make_me_collapisble").collapsible()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add it with the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.
Like so:
 `$(".make_me_collapsible").attr("data-role","collapsible");`

Comment: Now it works: 
$(document).delegate("#pageone", "pagebeforecreate", function() { 
$(".make_me_collapsible").attr("data-role","collapsible");
});

Comment: Thanks for the answers.